# App Intent definition changed, but it is not synced to the Shortcuts app

Tags: sirishortcuts, appintents

I'm changing an App Intent definition, but the changes are not reflected in the Shortcuts app when I try to use my changed intent as an action in a Shortcut.

And trying to run the shortcut gives an exception:

> [Execution] perform() returned types not declared in method signature
>
> AppIntents/PerformActionExecutorTask.swift:78: Fatal error: perform() returned types not declared in method signature

Is there a way to force reload the Shortcuts app to get the new intents or am I missing something more basic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. When returning a result together with a value the return definition of the `perform()` function needs to include `IntentResult` like so:

```swift
// Works as described ✅
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<String> {
    return .result(value: "Some text")
}
```

Including just `ReturnsValue<String>` will result in the exception above and modified version of the intent will not be picked up by the compiler.

```swift
// Incorrect function annotation ❌
func perform() async throws -> some ReturnsValue<String> {
    return .result(value: "Some text")
}
```