# Adding intent to the AppIntentsExtension

Tags: macos, appintents

I have added an "App Intents Extension" target to my main application in macOS. This generated the below two files:

**TWAppIntent.swift**

```swift
import AppIntents
    
struct TWAppIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "TWAppIntent"
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Get information on \(\.$TWType)")
    }
        
    @Parameter(title: "TWType")
    var TWType: String
        
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {         
        return .result(dialog: "Executed TWAppIntent.")
    }
}
```

**TWAppIntentExtension.swift**

```swift
import AppIntents
    
@main
struct TWAppIntentExtension: AppIntentsExtension {
        
}
```

I m able to build the extension target and I my intent action is available in the shortcuts app. However, on launching a shortcut with the above created intent action. I m getting the below popups:

[image]
[image]

From what I understand, I m getting this error because I have not added my 'TWAppIntent' to the TWAppIntentExtension.swift file which is the entry point for the extension, but I could not find any documentation around how to add it. Can someone help on how to do it or Is there something else that I m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To debug App Intents and find out what’s the actual error behind the generic one you are saying, it’s very useful to use the *Console* app on macOS, stream your device's logs and filter the output with the name of your app: you will often find detailed errors.

In this case, the error is most likely that you are providing a dialog without specifying `ProvidesDialog` in the return type of `perform()`

```swift
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        return .result(dialog: "Executed TWAppIntent.")
    }
```

It used to be more flexible on iOS 16, but with iOS 17, according also to [App Intent definition changed, but it is not synced to the Shortcuts app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75152126/5928873), you have to specify what you want to return.